# ReCapatcha v3 in a contact form - best practice for preventing false positives

Tags: forms, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I've got a contact form that currently uses ReCaptcha v2 for spam protection. I'm looking into switching to v3 but I feel I have a missing puzzle piece..
If google recognises a user as a robot (gives him a low score), can I give him a chance to prove he isn't one? Do I trust google blindly and just discard his submission, assuming he is indeed a robot?

Is there a known best practice for this case, or am I basically just describing ReCaptcha v2..
Thanks!

Comment: I used to use V2, but V3 is giving a lot of false positives. I am not sure if you can somehow change the threshold level. I don't think V3 at this stage can give your user an option to prove they are not a robot.